# Nested UITableView dynamic height

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

I need to have a nested UITableView in a tableView cell (actually, two tables in one cell) to show different lists with dynamic content (so, I need dynamic heights). My nested tables will not have scrolling—I need them just to order elements of different kinds, like texts, pictures, fields etc. To be more clear—the first level is the level of operations and every operation can have a variable amount of instructions and actions. Instructions and actions should be placed side by side and the operation cell should have the size of the tallest table.

There are no problems in nesting tables, but I faced a problem with the auto layout. I’ve tried everything that I could find, but with no success.

I tried height constraints for nested table views, which I update on the operation cell creation from tableview.contentsize.hight, but it seems that contentsize returns height based on the estimated size of every row, but not the actual size.

I tried to rewrite intrinsic content size of nested tables:

```
UITableView {

    override var contentSize:CGSize {
        didSet {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        return CGSize(width: UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric, height: contentSize.height)
    }
}
```

Nothing works properly. Any ideas how it could be solved?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set Inner tableview my custom class `AGTableView` and height Constraint both are required,

this class set `contantSize` same table view height Constraint.

Check out Github [AutoHeightIncrementTableViewDemo](https://github.com/AshvinGudaliya/AutoHeightIncrementTableViewDemo)

```
class AGTableView: UITableView {

    fileprivate var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override init(frame: CGRect, style: UITableViewStyle) {
        super.init(frame: frame, style: style)
        self.associateConstraints()
        defaultInit()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.associateConstraints()
        defaultInit()
    }

    func defaultInit(){
        self.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
        self.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        self.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        self.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        self.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        self.sectionFooterHeight = 0
        self.sectionHeaderHeight = 0
    }

    override open func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if self.heightConstraint != nil {
            self.heightConstraint.constant = self.contentSize.height
        }
        else{
            print("Set a heightConstraint to set cocontentSize with same")
        }
    }

    func associateConstraints() {
        // iterate through all text view's constraints and identify
        // height

        for constraint: NSLayoutConstraint in constraints {
            if constraint.firstAttribute == .height {
                if constraint.relation == .equal {
                    heightConstraint = constraint
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Also set a `estimatedRowHeight`

```
self.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.estimatedRowHeight = height
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you clarify please—do I need to do something with the outer tableView (or its cell)?

Comment: Make a Outer Tableview cell size is auto increment. and set this class in inner tableview.

Comment: This class set a height of table view same like as you tableview content size.

Comment: Can’t make it work :-( It seems I missed something. The hight constant updates, but it’s late for the outer cell, I presume. Could you please take a look at https://github.com/AlexChekanov/TaskCard-Table-in-Table? It’s a setup with your solution.

Comment: It works! Thank you! You saved my day (or even three days :-)

Comment: @AlexeyChekanov can you share that repo once more, it is not public anymore. Trying to resolve the same issue :-( Thanks!

Comment: I uploaded my new demo check out this.

Comment: @AshvinGudaliya Hi, where do we set this `nsHeightConstraint` that is in your repo. I can't figure it out

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi https://github.com/AshvinGudaliya/AutoHeightIncrementTableViewDemo/blob/master/AutoHeightIncrementTableViewDemo/Classes/AGTableView.swift

Comment: @AshvinGudaliya reference to your answer, can I ask one question related to UITableView height?

Comment: @Tekhe Yes, you can

Comment: @AshvinGudaliya Thank you. I have tried to follow your coding procedure which you have mentioned for nested one but it in parent table it half hides onload then if I click all tableView all rows visible. How can I set dynamic Parent child height  for my nested tableView. here is the link https://github.com/MasamMahmood/autoHeightTableView